# Chrome --kiosk-printing doesn't print pictures

Tags: google-chrome, printing, printing-web-page

Until recently, several of my end users were able to print from a website using a shortcut with a target of `"https://secure-site" -printing"`. (I didn't forget a double quote, it's just the one at the end.)  Using `--kiosk-printing` will print text, but not pictures from this particular internal site.

All normal & public websites will print just fine.  So, I'm not sure if this special internal site changed something, or there was a Chrome change that broke our ability to hide the print dialog box.

Is there a change to the website that I can look for using DevTools, or someway to troubleshoot this? Or a new way to hide the print dialog box?  If the dialog box has to popup, my end user needs to then click the print button for 50-75 different prints. The continuous print option speeds up the process a lot.

I may have to write a PowerShell script where the user just needs to enter their login credentials. If that's the only answer, then so be it.